# How should i run a background thread in c# > 4.0

Tags: c#, async-await

I have mainly been reusing a code snippet from old times:

```
 public void Start()
        {
            renewalThread = new Thread(() =>
            {

                while (!disposed)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

                    try
                    {

                        if (LogUpdated != null)
                            update();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }

            });
            renewalThread.Start();
        }
```

Are there more elegant ways to do this, thinking about the new async/await stuff?
What are the main differences to a solution doing something like

```
Task.run( () =>
{
await Task.delay(10000);

update code
}, __.LongRunning);
```

Comment: I would not use threads, I would use a `Timer`.

Comment: Could you update the answer telling why also.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `Timer` instead:

```
    aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);

    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

    aTimer.Enabled = true;

private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
// do something here.
// if this method could take longer than the intervale, disable the
// timer at the start and re-enable at the end.
}
```

With `Timer` you don't have to start a new thread.  `Thread.Sleep` forces you to use a thread that sits and waits.  If you want to do something every x seconds, that's what `System.Threading.Timer` is designed for, it will take a thread-pool thread and use that when calling the event and the thread will only be in use during the event--unlike `Sleep`.  `Sleep` is inaccurate--it could be less than the time you asked for or more.  the likelihood of it being that much off with 10 seconds is nil; but it's sill inaccurate.  Using `thread.Sleep` means you can't do two events at once--if your `Timer` event handler took more time than the interval, it would run two handlers at a time.  A `Timer` is much easier to stop--you just call `Stop` or `Dispose`.  With `Thread.Sleep` you have to use `Thread.Abort`--and risk data corruption (i.e. you have to write the code that calls `Thread.Sleep` in such a way that cancelling the thread doesn't corrupt data).  If you need to do something on the UI thread in the event, use `Forms.Timer` and you don't have to deal with marshalling back to the UI thread (e.g. `Control.BeginInvoke`).

I could go on, but I think you get the point.  For more details, see http://bit.ly/IhxHSk